# How to show SVG donut chart in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I have created a very nicely animated chart that looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/033v79qo/1/).

```
<div>Some percentage</div>
<div class="bigbox">
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="item t1">
      <div class="graphicsContent">51%</div>
      <svg width="144px" height="144px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g>
          <title>Layer 1</title>
          <circle id="circle1" class="circle_animation" r="56" cy="72" cx="72" stroke-width="16" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle id="innerCircle1" r="44" cy="72" cx="72" stroke-width="2" stroke="#b1b1b1" fill="none"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I used SVG. It seems to work fine anywhere else but in IE. I read that IE has a lot of issues regarding CSS3 animations. SMIL doesn't seem to solve my problems. And I don't even care if the graphic is completely animated in IE as long as it just shows the whole content.

Should I stay away from SVG if I want to create a cross-browser solution or is there something I should add to achieve the desired (or even partially desired) result in IE? I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: which version of IE?

Comment: I tested it with 11. I used the developer tools in IE to try older versions and 10, as far as I tested, doesn't display it right either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Dash-arrayoffset animated

**Does not work in IE**, even if the [documentation][1] does say its css animatable  
So **[Harry][2]** converted it to use dash-array instead.

I reveresed the prosess with: `animation: t1 1s ease-out reverse forwards;`

Why would you do that?
Because when an animation fails in IE it goes back to its initial value.
The old initial value was: `stroke-dasharray: 351.68;`
this is 0% of the circle
The new initial value is: `stroke-dasharray: 170.7, 351.68;`
and this is about 51% of the circle.

```css
.bigbox {
  width: 50%;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
}
.graphicsContent {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 144px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.250em;
}
svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 170.7, 351.68;
}
.t1 .circle_animation {
  -webkit-animation: t1 1s ease-out reverse forwards;
  animation: t1 1s ease-out reverse forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes t1 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 170.7, 351.68;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 351.68;
  }
}
@keyframes t1 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 170.7, 351.68;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 351.68;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Some percentage</div>
<div class="bigbox">
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="item t1">
      <div class="graphicsContent">51%</div>
      <svg width="144px" height="144px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g>
          <title>Layer 1</title>
          <circle id="circle1" class="circle_animation" r="56" cy="72" cx="72" stroke-width="16" stroke="blue" fill="none" />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle id="innerCircle1" r="44" cy="72" cx="72" stroke-width="2" stroke="#b1b1b1" fill="none" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you say, 'SMIL doesnt seem to your your problems' - The reason behind this is because IE does not suspport SVG SMIL animation - as you can see here http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20animation

Would you be happy with the whole chart (i.e. the circle and the blue bar with percentage) being displayed, or just the percentage without the circle?

Comment: I would be happy with the whole chart being displayed (inner circle + blue bar). The animation might not work for IE, I am fine with that.

Comment: I do not see how SMIL animations is related to this problem at all